# I am having this issue with a script that I wrote that is giving me an error as shown below. Please advise

Tags: python, json

My code is as follows:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher




description_file = open("description.json", encoding="utf-8")


nodescription_file = open("nodescription.json",  encoding="utf-8")


desc = json.load(description_file)
nodesc = json.load(nodescription_file)


stack = []
def get_values():
    data = []
    for pages in nodesc:
        for rows in pages["dataRows"]:
            skip = False
            if skip:
                break
            email = ""
            companyname = rows["columnValues"]["companyName"][0]["name"]
            fullname = ""
            firmName = rows["columnValues"]["firm"][0]["name"]
            pbid = rows["columnValues"]["companyName"][0]["pbId"]
            managementposition = rows["columnValues"]["managementPosition"][0]["value"]
            
            if len(rows["columnValues"]["email"]):
                email = rows["columnValues"]["email"][0]["value"]
            else:
                email = "No email"
            
            if len(rows["columnValues"]["fullName"]):
                 fullname = rows["columnValues"]["fullName"][0]["name"]
         
            for desc_rows in desc["dataRows"]:
                pbid_desc = desc_rows["columnValues"]["investorName"][0]["pbId"]
                
                description = ""
                if len(desc_rows["columnValues"]["description"]):
                    description = desc_rows["columnValues"]["description"][0]["value"]
                else:
                    description = "No description"
                
                if pbid == pbid_desc:
                    data.append({"Full Name": fullname, "Email": email, "Company Name": companyname, "Position":managementposition, "Description": description})
                
    save_data(data, "file7.csv")
                       
                        

def similar(a, b): #Dont use this anymore, pbid was relational
    
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

def instack(string):
    for i in stack:
        if string == i:
            return True
    return False

def save_data(data, name):
    pd.read_json(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'), encoding='utf-8').to_csv(name, encoding="utf-8")
get_values()
description_file.close()
nodescription_file.close()
```

I am getting an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dan/Desktop/Upwork/main.py", line 69, in <module>
    get_values()
  File "/Users/dan/Desktop/Upwork/main.py", line 53, in get_values
    save_data(data, "file7.csv")
  File "/Users/dan/Desktop/Upwork/main.py", line 68, in save_data
    pd.read_json(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8'), encoding='utf-8').to_csv(name, encoding="utf-8")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 207, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 588, in read_json
    json_reader = JsonReader(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 673, in __init__
    data = self._get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py", line 710, in _get_data_from_filepath
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 826, in get_handle
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <class 'bytes'> type
```

Please help - I am a total noob. Thank you so much. The above is not code it is an error and the stackoverflow autobot is making be write more of a questions because it cannot discern the code text from the result text - or I am just a noob. Please help. Thank you so much in advance. I am on PC using Visual Studio and have already installed pip pandas and pip cdifflib is not installing for some reason with exit code 1120 legacy install failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is because `read_json` expects as a fisrt argument either a path to a file or a file-like object, but you're giving it a bytes string.

I think what should work is to convert your bytes string into a bytes buffer that is a file-like object, with io.BytesIO :

```
pd.read_json(io.BytesIO(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')), encoding='utf-8').to_csv(name, encoding="utf-8")
```